# I want that my teammates run faster. Did I write the underlined part of sentence below right

Tags: simple-past

I want that my teammates run faster. Did I write the underlined part of sentence below right?

"I screamed for my teammates **to they run quicker**"

Comment: You might want to migrate this question to [English Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

The outright error is that you have slipped a pronoun into an infinitive verb.  It should be

> I screamed for my teammates to run quicker.

Also, "quick" is generally reserved for short, abrupt actions.  Actions over time are characterized as "fast".

> I screamed for my teammates to run faster.